# How to check if query returns no results and use a different query instead?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this query to show results if today equals to a date saved in database.

```
$sh = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE  DATE(:today) = DATE(`start`)');
$sh->bindValue(":today", $today);
$sh->execute();
while($row = $sh->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
here is my code when results are found
}
```

However, if there is no results, I would like to repeat the above code changing only the query to this

`SELECT * FROM events WHERE`city`= (:city) AND DATE(:start) Between DATE(`start`) and DATE(`end`)`

What is a good way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in one query, you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE  DATE(:today) = DATE(`start`)
union all
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE city= (:city) AND DATE(:start) Between DATE(start) and DATE(end) and
      not exists (SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATE(:today) = DATE(`start`));
```

EDIT:

If you are trying to get 3 rows, prioritized by the first query but not the second, then do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE  DATE(:today) = DATE(`start`) or
       (city= (:city) AND DATE(:start) Between DATE(start) and DATE(end))
order by DATE(:today) = DATE(`start`) desc, rand()
limit 3;
```

Comment: It worked great! Do you think this is an optimized way of handling this situation?

Comment: The question of efficiency depends on factors such as the indexing on the table.  On a table with no indexing, this would be slightly less performant than running each query independently.

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer. I have one last question though, I `limit 3` the results but I can't get it working when I use `order by rand() limit 3`. Is there something else on this?